# jQuery Ajaxy Plugin callback before triggering state change

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

I am using Ajaxy Plugin for attempting to restore ajax requests history.

Considering de code:

```
$.Ajaxy.configure({
    'Controllers': {
        '_generic': {
            request : function() {},
            response: function(){
                var data = this.State.Response.data; 
                jQuery('#content').html(data.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have this line

var data = this.State.Response.data;

that injects the responseText to the #content element.

But I may need to run some code before requesting the page to create a url and define a target id before triggering an ajax request.

for example, supposing I have a product listing page (not a real code, I just created for this question):

```
<button data-id="1" data-controller="product" data-action="edit" onClick="getPage(this, '#editContainer1');" >Edit</a>
<button data-id="1" data-controller="product" data-action="remove" onClick="getPage(this, '#removeContainer1');" >Remove</a>
<hr>
<button data-id="2" data-controller="product" data-action="edit" onClick="getPage(this, '#editContainer2');" >Edit</a>
<button data-id="2" data-controller="product" data-action="remove" onClick="getPage(this, '#removeContainer2");" >Remove</a>
<hr>
```

lots of results, maybe have incremented ID....

Having a javascript code that does the following:

```
function getPage(element, target)
{
    var id = jQuery(element).data('id');
    var controller = jQuery(element).data('controller');
    var action = jQuery(element).data('action');
    var url = "/" + controller + "/" + action + "/" + id;
    jQuery.get(url,function(responseText){jQuery(target).html(responseText)});
}
```

So, how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your request correctly...
you don't need onClick actions in the HTML elements:
HTML:

```
<button data-id="1" data-controller="product" data-action="edit" >Edit</a>
<button data-id="1" data-controller="product" data-action="remove">Remove</a>
<hr>
<button data-id="2" data-controller="product" data-action="edit">Edit</a>
<button data-id="2" data-controller="product" data-action="remove">Remove</a>
<hr>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $('button[data-controller=product]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var composedURL = "/"+$(this).data('controller')+"/"+$(this).data('action')+"/"+id
        $.ajax({
            url: composedURL,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // called when ajax request was successful
            console.log("success");
            if($(this).attr('data-action')=='edit'){
                // clicked EDIT button
                $('#editContainer'+id).html(data);
            }
            else{
                // clicked REMOVE button
                $('#removeContainer'+id).html(data);
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // called when there was an error
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            // called when request finished (regardless of error or success)
            console.log("complete");
        });

    })
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your time for answering by question, but I indeed forgot to paste the lines mentioning the plugin itself. I have updated it now

Comment: if this is your intended workflow: button click->create url->call ajax function->get response->output response to proper container, then my answer still applies, this code will create an ajax call when you click a button and then get the response data (same as you have data in your plugin code)